# Get one or more files from Source Control Explorer into TEMP folder

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-foxpro, source-control-explorer

I am working on VFP projects, but our source control is TFS.  I would like to be able to get files from TFVC and redirect them from the workspace into the TEMP folder so I can easily use a 3rd party file compare utility against them.  I can do this with Vault source control.  Is there a way to get a file from TFS source control and put it into the TEMP (or any other folder) without creating the project folder structure (making a new Workspace pointing to the temp folder creates the folder structure)?

Comment: Why you want to store the files in a temp folder for using 3rd party file compare utility against them? You could also be able to change the default compare tool in VS to achieve this. Tools-Option-Source Control-Visual Studio Team Foundation Sever-Configure Tools

Comment: The problem is that in VFP, the forms, class, and menus are actually stored in DBFs (binary), so I have a tool that reads the DBF and converts the contents to text so I can compare them.  That's why i want to get the TFS files and drop them into a TEMP folder.For example, you will have Form1.scx & Form1.sct where the scx file has the records for each object and the sct has the metadata for each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't the build-in feature to redirect files into other folders.

You can create a new workspace and add mappings to the corresponding folders, then switch workspace that you want and get files.

If you want the different folder structure, you can map the corresponding server folders to different folders. More information, you can refer to [Optimize your workspace](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/optimize-your-workspace).

Comment: This is precisely what I had to do due to the TFVC limitation on redirecting check-out/get.  Now I have 2 workspaces for my VFP projects, one in my regular dev folder structure and on in my temp folder structure.  I don't like it, but it's all that can be done as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  `...%TMP%\TFSTemp` folder concept in TFS. However it's only used for files that you view.

> For example: If you view the history of a file in TFS you can view
>   any version you want.  Simply right click on an older version and
>   select view from the context menu. Hover over the tab in Visual Studio
>   and you will see the file was downloaded to the TFSTemp folder.  That
>   file is not check out or download  to you and you are just viewing
>   that file.

It's not used for storing TFS version control files.

Comment: That's not going to work because.  The files I need are binary and are paired, as I mentioned above.  Forms, for example, consist of 2 files, .SCX and .SCT.  They are actually Foxpro dbf file and memo file.  They are opened as one unit.  I need to "get" both at the same time to put them into the temp (or any) folder.

Comment: All I want to do is "get" a file from VC and redirect it into any folder I choose at "get" time.